# Show selective data after post request

Tags: jquery, django, post, python-3.x

I have a web page with form and submit button. (user should input text here and push "Ok" button) I send this data with using post request on my django server. Then, server return a dictionary with elements. I want make some buttons on my web page, for example N1, N2, N3 buttons. When user pushed N1 button, I want to show only value of key N1. How can I do this?

My html side:

```
<div class="form-container">
    <form class="forms" action="{% url 'analyze' %}" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <ol>
                <textarea class="text-area required" name="source">{{ text }}</textarea>
            </ol>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="analyze" name="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

My server side:

```
def analyze(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text = request.POST.get('source')
        try:
            kanji = KanjiesText(text)
            results = [
                {'id': 1, 'value': kanji.n1, 'percent': 100 * len(kanji.n1) / len(N1)},
                {'id': 2, 'value': kanji.n2, 'percent': 100 * len(kanji.n2) / len(N2)},
                {'id': 3, 'value': kanji.n3, 'percent': 100 * len(kanji.n3) / len(N3)},
                {'id': 4, 'value': kanji.n4, 'percent': 100 * len(kanji.n4) / len(N4)},
                {'id': 5, 'value': kanji.n5, 'percent': 100 * len(kanji.n5) / len(N5)}
            ]
            return render_to_response('kanji_analyzer/main.html', {'text': text, 'results': results})
        except KanjiesTextError as e:
            return render_to_response('kanji_analyzer/main.html', {'text': text, 'error': e})
    else:
        return render_to_response('kanji_analyzer/main.html')
```

P.S. I don't want use  block with attribute display:none.

Comment: where you want to show buttons? wich template?

Comment: I have a two template. Main template (without additional buttons) and adding template after sending text by user. I wanna add buttons into my second template.

Answer (score 0):

Use This in your template:

```
{% for result in results %}
    <button type="button" >N{{result.id}}</button>
{% endfor %}
```